# Vim autocmd runs erroneously on readonly

Tags: vim

Among other things, I have in my `.vimrc` file the following:

```
function! BashHeader()
    source ~/.vim/bash_header.txt
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile *.bash,*.sh :call BashHeader()
```

The file `bash_header.txt` just has a boilerplate header I want at the top of my bash script files.

At first glance, this works great – `vim somefile` gives me no header, while `vim somescript.bash` automatically inserts the header.  The trouble comes when I use the startup mode shortcut `view`.  `view`, as [this Vim documentation describes](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vim-arguments), is a shortcut for starting Vim in readonly mode, like `vim -R somefile`.  But when I start Vim in this manner, opening a file that already exists, I get the following message:

```
$> view somefile
"somefile" "somefile" [readonly] 6L, 359C
Error detected while processing ~/.vim/bash_header.txt:
line    2:W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced the real path to my .vim directory with `~`; I don't think this is an important omission.</sup>

Clearly, Vim is trying to add a header to this file, despite the facts that

1. `somefile` already exists (and should not trigger the BufNewFile event required for my `autocmd`), and
2. `somefile` doesn't even end in `.bash` or `.sh`, so it should not trigger the pattern required by my `autocmd`.

And indeed, once I press enter, my bash header has been inserted into this readonly buffer.

To further complicate matters, invoking Vim in readonly mode explicitly, as in `vim -R somefile` does *not* display the same erroneous behavior.  That works just as expected.

What am I missing?

---

**EDIT:** Here are the contents of `bash_header.txt`:

```
:insert
#! /bin/bash
#==============================================================================
# $Author$
# $Date$
# $HeadURL$
# $Revision$
#==============================================================================
.
```

Further, running `view -u NONE somefile` does not exhibit the error.  I had a thought – perhaps my `.vimrc` was not being evaluated when using the `view` alias, but only when using `vim`.  As a simply test, I added

```
echo ".vimrc was run."
```

to my `.vimrc` file.  A-ha! When I run `vim somefile`, I see the message printed, but not when I run `view somefile`.  So now my question becomes, what would cause `vim` to use my `.vimrc`, but `view` not to? And how, then, is `view` getting hold of my `bash_header.txt` even though it does not appear to be evaluating my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Please share `~/.vim/bash_header.txt`.

If that file really only contains boilerplate, you shouldn't use `:source` because Vim will execute its content as if it was Vimscript. For quick and dirty templating, you are supposed to us `:0r ~/.vim/bash_header.txt`.

Also, I can't replicate your problem here: the `autocmd` is not run when I do `view`. You should reduce your config to its base components to refine your question:

1. What is the content of `~/.vim/bash_header.txt`?
2. What happens without plugins? With an empty `~/.vimrc`?
3. Use the exact path of your files.